# How do i set my composer.json on github to allow inclusion as a library?

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php

All of the documentation and tutorials and forums I've looked at are about setting up a client composer.json for downloading other people's packages, but I'm trying to set up my own packages, ZF2 modules, so I can include them in multiple projects. This is my hello-world attempt. I have a shiny-rest repository which depends on the shiny-lib repository, and I want to specify the dependency with numeric(al?) version numbers. shiny-rest's composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "shinymayhem/shiny-rest",
    "description": "REST with JSON, XML and api-problem style errors",
    "license": "Apache 2.0",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Reese Wilson",
            "email": "EMAIL"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "0.0.x-dev"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "shinymayhem/shiny-lib": "0.0.*",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "url": "https://github.com/shinymayhem/shiny-lib",
            "type": "git"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "ShinyRest": "src"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "Module.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

shiny-lib's composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "shinymayhem/shiny-lib",
    "description": "Base lib with Xml2Array trait",
    "license": "Apache 2.0",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Reese Wilson",
            "email": "EMAIL"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "0.0.x-dev"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "ShinyLib": "src"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "Module.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

When I require shiny-rest: dev-master on my client's composer.json (which includes minimum stability: dev), it resolves the shiny-rest repository correctly,  but then says

```
shinymayhem/shiny-rest dev-master requires shinymayhem/shiny-lib 0.0.* -> no matching package found.
```

I've tried a couple different things, like following the [documentation at getcomposer.org](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md), or trying to copy other repositories that work as composer packages, but I'm just guessing and checking. How do you specify versions and dependencies and aliases in the source package composer.json? Is there some good documentation somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client's composer.json needs to include the repository line for your shiny lib:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "url": "https://github.com/shinymayhem/shiny-lib",
        "type": "git"
    }
],
```

The repository line in your `shiny-rest` composer.json is ignored when you include that lib in other projects - additional repositories can only be specified in the root composer.json. This is a security feature in Composer to prevent 3rd party libraries from specifying from overriding the standard repos for other 3rd party libraries.

Comment: that did the trick, but how do people automatically include dependencies? does it require using packagist? how does this one do it? https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/composer.json

Comment: Yup, register it with packagist and then there's no need to manually set the repository URL.

Comment: zf2's composer.json specifies `sebastianbergmann/phpcov` as a dependency with a repository url. phpcov doesn't appear to be registered with packagist, and installing zf2 with `--dev` does install that package

Comment: Hmm, this is news to me. Perhaps that's something that only works with the `--dev` flag.

Comment: I tested with that, doesn't seem to make a difference. This page seems to suggest it shouldn't work, so I don't really know what is going on: https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-can't-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md
Anyway, I'm giving up and going with packagist

Comment: @rwilson04 If you look at [#L15](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/composer.json#L15) You will see that ZF2 is defining `sebastianbergmann/phpcov` as a package: Check the composer [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2) for a description :)